# Java - text to 2d array remove spaces"

Tags: java, arrays

have the text file containing a 2d array with a fixed row and column [6][3]

```
a 5 7
b 9 7
c 1 0
d 0 5
e 8 7
f 0 4
```

i need to put the data into array `playerOne[][]`

This is my code

```
try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    String line = sc.next().trim();
                    if (line.length() > 0) {
                        playerOne[i][j] = line;
                        System.out.println(i+ " " +j+ " "+ line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(playerOne));
}
```

i get an NoSuchElementException error, and it cannot print the array

Comment: never use `next()` it reads newline as a separate character. Instead use `nextLine()` and `split()` to make a string array

Comment: @skrer actually using next() is better

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I may be wrong but I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: sure, .nextLine getting the whole line then you have to split it into array 
however .next will get the next value regardless to the next value line

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `nextLine` use `.next` directly 
.next will get the next value regardless to the next value line

```
try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    String nextValue= sc.next().trim();
                        playerOne[i][j] = nextValue;
                        System.out.println(i+ " " +j+ " "+ nextValue);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(playerOne));
}
```